# Unable to make http calls within Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am having an azure function(f1) which makes http call to another azure function(f2) that has a http trigger. Both are written in java and I am using simple HttpClient. Here is the code block.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet("https://test.azurewebsites.net/api/test");
HttpResponse response =  client.execute(httpRequest);;
```

I tested f2 in browser which gives expected response. But when i run f1 it keeps loading and finally throws me an error

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you check your logs for any errors being logged there? or can you share your app name either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Function chaining in durable functions.

Function chaining refers to the pattern of executing a sequence of functions in a particular order. Often the output of one function needs to be applied to the input of another function.

The values "F1", "F2" are the names of other functions in the function app.

```
public static async Task<object> Run(DurableOrchestrationContext ctx)

    {
        try
        {
            var x = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("F1");
            return  await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("F2", x);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // error handling/compensation goes here
        }
    }
```

Check this reference document -

[Durable Functions - Pattern #1: Function chaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-1-function-chaining)